# Ranking columns based on variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this-

```
  Metric       Value         Model
f1_measure  0.854053454   Logistic_Regression
auc         0.927363382   Logistic_Regression
precision   0.871229558   Logistic_Regression
f1_measure  0.957372309   Random_Forest
auc         0.994050551   Random_Forest
precision   0.974012599   Random_Forest
f1_measure  0.823266765   Naive_Bayes
auc         0.91573591    Naive_Bayes
precision   0.83156611    Naive_Bayes
```

Now I want to create another data frame-

```
       Model_name         Rank      Metric
 
      Random_Forest          1        auc
      Logistic_Regression    2        auc
      Naive_Bayes            3        auc
```

This data frame is created using the Metric==`'auc'` which is given by the user. I need to create a new data frame with the rank based on the user given metric value as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using boolean indexing to extract what you need, assign rank and sort:

```
(df[df.Metric=='auc']
   .assign(Rank=lambda x: x['Value'].rank(ascending=False))
   .sort_values('Rank')
)
```

Output:

```
  Metric     Value                Model  rank
4    auc  0.994051        Random_Forest   1.0
1    auc  0.927363  Logistic_Regression   2.0
7    auc  0.915736          Naive_Bayes   3.0
```

Comment: I wanted ranks in descending,with highest having rank 1

Answer (score 1):

Use `boolean indexing` to filter the dataframe where metric equals `auc`, then use [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) to rank the the filtered dataframe on column `Value`, finally use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort the dataframe to `Rank`:

```
df1 = df[df.Metric.eq('auc')]
df1 = df1.assign(Rank=df1.pop('Value').rank(ascending=False)).sort_values(by='Rank')
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)

  Metric                Model  Rank
4    auc        Random_Forest   1.0
1    auc  Logistic_Regression   2.0
7    auc          Naive_Bayes   3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
df[df.Metric == 'auc'].sort_values(by = 'Value', ascending = False)
```

Comment: And the rank column?